# Session attacks, what are the new breeds of attacks?

Tags: security, http, session

I am collecting as information as possible about http(s) session attacks.

There is a plenty of information about existing attacks, but, i would like to know if some new breeds of attacks are now made possible either by security flaws in popular software or technologies or by new smarter security engineering.

Do you have some recommendations about new techniques or tools ?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you looking for techniques or tools to defend against session attacks, or are you looking for tools to allow you to make attacks?

Comment: I would like to collect information about new techniques and tools that will lead to future attack patterns. The goal of this investigation is to improve a session management system. So, that's why i am asking that question to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a very recent attack against HTTPS.  The tool to perform this attack is called [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) and was introduced in the blackhat 2009 talk by Moxie Marlinspike.  I highly recommend watching the video on that page.

So far chrome is the only browser that has a partial fix for this issue.  The [patch is called STS](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20100413/chrome-fixes-sts-privacy-issue/) and it must be enabled by the developer.   Firefox is working on supporting STS.  Microsoft and Apple are slow to adopt new security measures,  they *should* eventually support this feature but as far as I know they haven't announced anything.

In terms of new attack patterns,  buffer overflows are on the way out and [Dangling Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) are in full swing.   [A Heap Overflow and a Dangling Pointer vulnerability where chained together](http://vreugdenhilresearch.nl/Pwn2Own-2010-Windows7-InternetExplorer8.pdf) to win the Pwn2own 2010 for IE under Windows 7.  Classic stack based buffer overflows are difficult to exploit on modern systems with NX-bit, Canaries and ASLR.  However Dangling Pointers can be used to bypass these new security measures.